# Appends a node with value `val` to the end of the list python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

i got a test program that needs to run without any errors.
and i got a different program defining the method
in this method i need to append a node with value of val to the end of a list
i have not a single clue how to get started and hope anyone could get me on my way!

for the method which is called opg1

```
class List:
    """ This implements a list using `Node` for its elements """
    class Node:
        """ A node consists of a value (val) and a  next-ptr (lnk) """
        def __init__(self, val, lnk=None):
            self.val = val
            self.lnk = lnk

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def append(self, val):
        """ Appends a node with value `val` to the end of the list.
        """
```

which is where i need to write the code to complete the test
and for the test:

```
from opg1 import *

# Test for List.append(val)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = List()
    l1 = List(List.Node("one"))
    l12 = List(List.Node("one", List.Node("two")))
    l123 = List(List.Node("one", List.Node("two", List.Node("three"))))
    for l, r in [
            ( l, "[four]" ),
            ( l1, "[one,four]" ),
            ( l12, "[one,two,four]" ),
            ( l123, "[one,two,three,four]" ),
            ]:
        l.append("four")
        if l.show() != r:
            print("Error: {} != {}".format(l.show(), r))
    print('End of Tests.')
```

Comment: If you don't have a clue on how to get started, I suggest revisiting the lesson that this assignment is intended to be practice for.

Comment: the point is that they don't give info and just throw us into the deep end
and i just wanna get it

Comment: can you add code of `List` class

Comment: there isn't any, the program is exactly like its up here just removed the pieces i was able to resolve which are seperate from this

Comment: The 2nd program is a test program, it imports the code from the def append

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
class List:
    """ This implements a list using `Node` for its elements """
    class Node:
        """ A node consists of a value (val) and a  next-ptr (lnk) """
        def __init__(self, val, lnk=None):
            self.val = val
            self.lnk = lnk

    def __init__(self, root=None):
        self.root = root

    def append(self, val):
        """ Appends a node with value `val` to the end of the list.
        """ 
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = List.Node(val)
        else:
            curr = self.root
            while curr.lnk:
                curr = curr.lnk
            curr.lnk = List.Node(val)
# Test for List.append(val)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    l = List()
    l.append('one')
    l.append('two')
    l.append('three')
    print(l.root.val, l.root.lnk.val, l.root.lnk.lnk.val)
    print('End of Tests.')
```

**Output:**

```
one two three
End of Tests.
```